# VBA sub call gives "compile error: Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected"

Tags: arrays, excel, argument-passing, vba

I have 2 Subs, both receive array as argument. one works fine, the other gives: compile error: Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected.
In the code written bellow, "InitializeArray" works and "PresentTotalRow" does not work.
Can anyone figure out why?

```
Sub PresentTotalRow(nCells As Integer, totalProductsPerDay() As Integer)
    row = nCells + MatrixRowOffset + 2
    Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 8)) = totalProductsPerDay
End Sub

Sub InitializeArray(ByRef arr() As Long)
    Dim N As Long
    For N = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(N) = 0
    Next N
End Sub


Sub ReadTxtFile()
    .....

    Dim totalProductsPerDay(0 To 6) As Long
    InitializeArray totalProductsPerDay

    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "C:\work\Documents\input.txt"

    Dim oFS As TextStream
    If oFSO.FileExists(filePath) Then

        Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath)
        ......
        i = 1
        Do While Not oFS.AtEndOfStream

            line = oFS.ReadLine
            ....
            nCells = calcNCells                

            totalProductsCounter = GetTotalProductsCounter()
            totalProductsPerDay(Day) = totalProductsPerDay(Day) + totalProductsCounter

            i = i + 1
        Loop

        PresentTotalRow nCells, totalProductsPerDay
        oFS.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "The file path is invalid.", vbCritical, vbNullString
    Exit Sub
End If

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub PresentTotalRow(nCells As Integer, totalProductsPerDay() As Integer)
    row = nCells + MatrixRowOffset + 2
    Range(Cells(row, 2), Cells(row, 8)) = totalProductsPerDay
End Sub
```

the second argument expects an integer array

```
PresentTotalRow nCells, totalProductsPerDay
```

you are passing an long array here as the second argument

Comment: Thanks. How stupid of me. The error message confused me, I thought that the array is not recognized as an array...